# Fetch and display SQL data from HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a table as (Contract-No, Vendor-Code) stored in MYSQL.

1. The user has to enter his Contract-No in the form and has to press the NEXT 
   button.
2. Next, I will fetch the entered Contract-No value through Java-Script and will show him another field where he has to enter his **Tracking No**.

   ***Now here is the tricky part***.
3. The **Tracking** No consists of a **Vendor-Code**+ 3 digit code
4. I am asked to fetch the vendor code stored in the DB through the Contract No 
   and display it on the screen and put a 3 digit field next to it. The user will enter his 3 digits unique code to complete the tracking number.

Now I can do it easily with PHP but the problem is that we cannot put PHP code in JavaScript nor can we use POST, GET methods from PHP until it is given in the action clause.

My form is bigger and has to be redirected to some other PHP file.

So can I please get some good ideas as to how I can approach the task. Please don't suggest me AJAX or JQuery as I am not allowed to use it for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

let me tell you a way

you are posting value to php & php processes the value and returns result in 2nd page return result to javascript variables like this

```
var r=<?php echo $result;?>;
```

to verify use onsubmit event in form to call verify matching